# Creating a default constructor for a stack

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012, stack

I am currently working on a project for class that requires us to implement a stack for integer use as a calculator. I am having problems with my default constructor and am wondering what I am missing.

```
OperandStack(int stackSize)
    {
        if (stackSize<=0)
            {cout<<"Must be positive"<<endl;}
        this->capacity=capacity;
        s =new double[stackSize];
        t=0;
    }
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: default ctor does not take any parameter- also for ctors taking primitives it is good practice to mark then explicit

Comment: @Sarang can you elaborate more? My understanding of constructors isn't the best as this is the first time I have had to implement one for a stack.

Comment: see this link for details on default ctor
http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/default_constructor

Answer (score 3):

> *" I am having problems with my default constructor and am wondering what I am missing."*

A [*default constructor*](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/default_constructor) takes no parameters, or declares default values for all of them. To cite from the linked reference documentation

> #### Default constructors
>
> A default constructor is a constructor which can be called with no arguments (either defined with an empty parameter list, or with default arguments provided for every parameter).

Thus your implementation should look like:

```
class OperandStack {
public:
     OperandStack(int stackSize = 10) 
                             // ^^^^ declare a default value
     // Better use a member initializer list, instead of initializing claas
     // members inside the constructor's body:
     : capacity(stackSize), s(new double[stackSize]), t(0) {
        if (stackSize<=0) {cout<<"Must be positive"<<endl;}
        // ^^^^ Better use an exception instead of this
        //      output statement (it's OK for basic debugging)
     }
};
```